# Send a reccurent mail with google script

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I try to create a code to send recurrent mails with google apps script at 16h45 approx (french's hour) but this code doesn't work and i don't know why.
This is my code :

```
function createTriggerTeletravail() {
ScriptApp.newTrigger('envoiMailTeletravail')
.timeBased()
.onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY)
.atHour(16).nearMinute(45).inTimezone('Europe/Paris')
.create(); }

function envoiMailTeletravail() {
// --- RÉCUPÉRATION DES ADRESSES MAILS
// Sheet contenant les adresses mails
var classeurMail = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var feuilleMails = classeurMail.getSheetByName('adresses_mails');

//Permet de connaître le nombres de cellules non vides dans la colonnes
var mails = feuilleMails.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
var nbMails = mails.filter(String).length;
// Remplissage de la variable email
var email = "";
for (let i = 0; i<nbMails; i ++){
  if (email == ""){
    email = mails[i];
  } else if (email != ""){
    email = email + "," + mails[i];
  }
} 
var sujet = 'Remplir le fichier de télétravail';
var corpsDuMail = '<p>Bonjour,</p>'
  + '<p> blablabla.</p>'
  + '<p>blablabla</p>'
  + '<p>blablabla</p>'
  + '<p>blablabla</p>'
  + '<p>blablabla</p>';

// Fonction permettant d'envoyer le mail
MailApp.sendEmail(email.toString(), sujet, corpsDuMail, {
htmlBody : corpsDuMail});
}
```

When i launch envoiMailTeletravail's function, it's work. It is linked to a sheet containing the email addresses that should receive the message.
I create three triggers in three separated files and none of three works.
Can you help me please because i don't know why its doesn't work

Comment: triggers are contained by projects not files.

Answer (score 1):

try this for creating your trigger:

```
function createTriggerTeletravail() {
  const t = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == 'envoiMailTeletravail');
  if (!t) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('envoiMailTeletravail').timeBased().onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY).atHour(16).nearMinute(45).inTimezone('Europe/Paris').create();
  }
}
```

It will help your to keep from creating too many triggers.

```
function envoiMailTeletravail() {
  var classeurMail = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = classeurMail.getSheetByName('adresses_mails');
  var email = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues().flat().join(',');
  var sujet = 'Remplir le fichier de télétravail';
  var corpsDuMail = '<p>Bonjour,</p>'
    + '<p> blablabla.</p>'
    + '<p>blablabla</p>'
    + '<p>blablabla</p>'
    + '<p>blablabla</p>'
    + '<p>blablabla</p>';

  // Fonction permettant d'envoyer le mail
  MailApp.sendEmail(email.toString(), sujet, corpsDuMail, {
    htmlBody: corpsDuMail
  });
}
```